# Function Names for sending and receiving RPCs?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, twisted, rpc

I'm using twisted. I have my protocols set up so that, to send an RPC, I do `protocol.send("update_status", data)`. To document which RPCs I've implemented, I make a separate function call for each one, so in this case I'd call `REQUEST_UPDATE_STATUS(data)` to send that RPC. When a protocol receives an RPC, a function gets called based on its name, in this case, `CMD_UPDATE_STATUS`.

The problem is that `REQUEST` and `CMD` are a bit awkward. I can mistake `REQUEST` as part of the command, for example, `REQUEST_NEW_DATA`, and that would end up triggering an RPC called `'new_data'`. However, `REQUEST_REQUEST_NEW_DATA` is just silly.

`CMD` is also awkward, as a `REQUEST_SEND_NEW_DATA` will become `CMD_SEND_NEW_DATA`, which is a bit awkward.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tip: Use PB... it's well designed and does exactly that

Second Tip: If the first tip isn't going to work for you, just do what PB does. On the client end a "callRemote("foo_func")" asks the server ot invoke the "foo_func" function on the server object. The server will then use "getattr(server_obj, "remote_" + "foo_func")" to find the remote method.  If the method exists, it's called. Otherwise an error is returned. The nice thing about this design is that it completely does away with your REQUEST... CMD... constants.

Comment: PB means Perspective Broker - http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/#auto4

Comment: hmm I could do this already.. instead of `protocol.send` I do `protocol.callRemote`, and instead of `CMD_SEND_NEW_DATA` i have `remote_sendNewData` or `REMOTE_sendNewData` as I prefer. i think i might have pretty much implemented PB.

Comment: I suggest you read through the Perspective Broker documentation. Anyone implementing RPC in Python would benefit from an understanding of PB's design as it contains several elegant solutions to common problems. The lighter-weight AMP protocol (also in twisted) is another good background source.